# retry on separate thread

Tags: java, producer-consumer

I am trying to re-process some task if they failed for the first time. I do not want to use completable future as it will open new threads and sessions so it doesn't seem scalable to me when we have lot of failures.

I am using dropwizard and at the start of my service, I am passing queue to Main class and consumer. Since, I think the main class is running on a separate thread, I do not think I need to re-create producer class again [not sure].

```
@Override
  public void run(PpsConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {
    final BlockingQueue<Object[]> queue  = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    new Thread(new Consumer(
         queue)).start(); //consumer at start of service
    
    environment.jersey().register(new MainClass(
            queue));
```

Consumer.java

```
public class Consumer extends MainClass implements Runnable {
  private final BlockingQueue<Object[]> queue;

  public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Object[]> queue) {
    super(queue);
    this.queue = queue;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {

    try {
      while (true) {
        Object[] take = queue.take();
        someFunction(take);

      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
  }

}
```

MainClass.java
This is the main class which was earlier processing everything. I am just showing the definition of the `someFunction`.

Let us suppose that frontend is triggering this function and is the entry point.

```
private int mainFunction(Object[] take) {

    if (process(take)) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        // putting into queue
        queue.add(take); //producer thread adding
      }
    }
    return 0;
    }

public int someFunction(Object[] take) {
    int val = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<10; i++){ // retry 10 times until it succeeds
      LOGGER.info("retry # {}", i+1);
      val = process(take);
      if(val == 1){
        break;
      }
    }
    return val;
  }
```

(1) Is my understanding correct i.e. I do not need to create a `producer.java` separately to add the tasks to `queue`.
(2) How and where can I return the val?
(3) Is there a way to retry a specific type of task after `n` seconds like using timestamp?

Comment: completable future will open new threads --- probably not always?

Comment: @LeiYang can you tell me how can I let all tasks run in same [single] thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do not want to use completable future as it will open new threads and sessions so it doesn't seem scalable to me *when we have lot of failures*.

I do not think you should modify or have to modify structure of component in almost its entirety for a corner\error case. dropwizard does provide two entry additional entry points which you can use to take care of this case:

1. Health Checks: https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/core.html#health-checks
2. Exception: https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/core.html#error-handling

I would prefer #1.

As for your questions:

> (1) Is my understanding correct i.e. I do not need to create a producer.java separately to add the tasks to queue.

Yes, though see below.

> (2) How and where can I return the val?

There does not seem to be a way to return to sender when you delay\retry tasks. You will need to insert the class handling retries in chain (Register). But I do not think it would be (easily) possible.

> (3) Is there a way to retry a specific type of task after n seconds like using timestamp?

I would think you should be accommodate this by creating your own configuration (https://www.dropwizard.io/en/latest/manual/core.html#configuration); perhaps multiple configuration classes that would represent multiple task types.